# prevent hardware back button to dismiss modal with android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m using Ionic 4 with Angular 8
I want to “Disable” modal dismiss when i press android hardware “back” button.

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("Button Pressed");
    });
```

I can trace the event but i can’t prevent ionic to dismiss modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
  console.log("Button Pressed");
  if (this.modalCtrl.getTop()) {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.getTop();
    if (modal) {
      console.log('ModalCtrl Top');
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please some explanation what your code does so that others can understand and it will also improve your answer....

Comment: Thanks for the answer but without explanation your code is useless. Did you test it before answer?

Comment: I have created a Subscriber for Back Button Press in Ionic 4.
When the hardware back button is pressed, it simply check if any Modal exists on the Top (using ModalController in Ionic) and pass if present else do nothing

Answer (score 3):

just add ModalOption `backdropDismiss: false`